# Add information in zend form and file upload fail

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have 2 problems. The first problem, that I have 2 input file (Zend_Form_Element_File) and each one of the input file have to redirect the file to a different directorys. I use Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http to up the files.

the files to view related with the problem is:

**Controller / Form / Upload Class**
http://pastebin.com/6hTADeMQ

The other problem it's that I have to show a name of file related with the record that I load in Form when I edit a record. How I can insert a div and print this information. Follow the Zend Form File: http://pastebin.com/TPAaiEPz